# Getting Products with proportion by CategoryId

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My query

```
var query = (from p in _productRepository.Table
join pv in _productVariantRepository.Table on p.Id equals pv.ProductId
where p.Published
&& !p.Deleted
&& pv.Published
&& !pv.Deleted
select p);
```

My Category tree is

```
383---------->Products GrandParent Category
   389------->Products Parent Category
      606---->Products Category
```

Following can also be the case that product does not have grandparent category

```
384------->Products Parent Category
   401----->Products Category
```

Now I have in all 6 categories which are top most i.e from 383-388.

I want to extract 18 products from the product list such that products from top most category(383-388) are divided equal. I.e if product with 383 as Parent or GrandParent category are 50 in numbers while for 385 its 25 then product from 383 will be double than that of 385
. So 18 products are selected by proportion of products by its parent or grandparent category.

If there are equal number of products for each one of 383-388 then 3-3 products will be selected from list.

Note that we can Take products category by `product.CategoryId` and `ParentCategoryId` by `_categoryService.GetParentCategoryById(product.CategoryId)`

Comment: You told us what you're going to do, but what's the question?

Comment: I want a query so that I can get Products in proportion by categoryid